# Set Min Value for Android Seek bar

Tags: android

```
private static int INCREMENT_BY = 10;
private static int MAX = 1000;
private static int MIN = 0;
SeekBar seekbar_min, seekbar_max;
private int max = 0, min = 0;


 seekbar_min.setProgress(MIN);
    seekbar_min.incrementProgressBy(INCREMENT_BY);
    seekbar_min.setMax(MAX);
    seekbar_min.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            progress = progress / INCREMENT_BY;
            progress = progress * INCREMENT_BY;
            if (progress < 100) {
                min = progress * 10;
            } else if (progress < 300) {
                min = progress * 50;
            } else if (progress < 900) {
                min = progress * 100;
            } else {
                min = progress * MAX;
            }
            tv_price_min.setText(String.valueOf(min));
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            if (seekBar.getProgress() != MIN || seekBar.getProgress() != MAX){
                if (seekBar.getProgress() < 100) {
                    max = seekBar.getProgress() + 10;
                } else if (seekBar.getProgress() < 300) {
                    max = seekBar.getProgress() + 50;
                } else if (seekBar.getProgress() < 900) {
                    max = seekBar.getProgress() + 100;
                } else {
                    max = seekBar.getProgress() + MAX;
                }
                seekbar_max.setProgress(max);
            }
        }
    });


    seekbar_max.incrementProgressBy(INCREMENT_BY);
    seekbar_max.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            progress = progress / INCREMENT_BY;
            progress = progress * INCREMENT_BY;
            if (progress < 100) {
                max = progress * 10;
            } else if (progress < 300) {
                max = progress * 50;
            } else if (progress < 900) {
                max = progress * 100;
            } else {
                max = progress * MAX;
            }
            tv_price_max.setText(String.valueOf(max));
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }
    });
```

The Seek bar is for maximum price must have the minimum value, which is Minimum Seek bar current value. I can do this successfully, but the problem is that, the maximum seek bar allows to change the min value to until 0, which i do not want.

Comment: You can't set min value you can just define max value.

Comment: The solution is convert 0 to your min value in progressChanged

Comment: No, I have  option to set min value using setProgress() method. But it works if user does not change the maximum seek bar  value, when user change maximum seek bar value, it  get changed.

Comment: In onProgressChange check if it was below your minimum value set it to min Value

Answer (score 11):

`Seekbar` does not have `setMin` function. The default minimum value is zero. If you want to set a Minimum Value for  `Seekbar`, then you have two options:

- Convert zero value to you minimum Value with some calculations.
- In [ProgressChange](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener) callback do not allow the value goes beyond the minimum with following snippet:

> ```
> if (seekbar.getProgress() < MIN_VALUE) {
>     seekbar.setProgress(MIN_VALUE);
> }
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Try this, I was able to do this on one of my projects. In this case, the maximum is 23 and the minimum is 8.

```
        seekBarLength = findViewById(R.id.seekBarLength);
        seekBarLength.setMax(23-8);
        seekBarLength.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                progress += 8;
                textViewPasswordLength.setText(progress + "");
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

actually You can't define the minimum value.
But there is Trick that i always Use:

in the "onProgressChanged" Metod, Put This Code

```
int min = 1;                                  //The Min Value You Want To
int progressValue;

if( i < min ) {                               // i : Progress Value
   progressValue = min;
   seekBar.setProgress(min);
                }else progressValue = i;
```

Answer (score -2):

I've kinda found way to do this easiest way (only API 26 and higher). There's a `setMin(int number)` method.

```
seekbar.setMax(6);
seekbar.setMin(1);
```

The catch is, you have to set minimum API in build gradle to 25 or higher

Comment: No a comprehensive solution, you need to support backward android versions!